# Convert LINQ codes to .Net 2.0 codes

Tags: c#, linq, .net-2.0

How should I convert LINQ codes below to .Net 2.0 codes?

I cannot upgrade it to .Net 3.5 due to <s>company policy</s> some constraints.

`GetErrorLog` will be use by `ObjectDataSource`.

In order for the code below to work, I use `System.Linq.Dynamic` from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

```
    public class errorLog
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public string filePath { get; set; }
    }

    public static IQueryable<errorLog> GetErrorLog(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, string logPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
        {
            sortExpression = "fileName";
        }
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(logPath);
        List<errorLog> files = new List<errorLog>();

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            files.Add(new errorLog { fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath = filePath });
        }

        return files.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortExpression).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
    }
```

Comment: *I cannot upgrade it to .Net 3.5 due to company policy.* Get a new company.

Comment: What have you tried? Linq makes life easy but it is not magic - Sort - you have many examples to do it. Skip - just take from index x onwards. Take - ...Just take until index y

Comment: Show an example of `sortExpression`, can you replace the one method with `GetErrorLogSortByName` and `GetErrorLogSortByPath`?

Comment: Your code does not compile!

Comment: With Microsoft's end of life support of raw .NET Framework 2.0 years ago, all supported setup should now be on .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and above. As the other comment indicates, don't waste your time on a dead platform.

Comment: @dotctor that might be because I use `System.Linq.Dynamic` from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Well, looky here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it, any better answers are welcome.

```
public static DataTable GetErrorLog(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, string logPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
    {
        sortExpression = "fileName DESC";
    }

    DataTable errorLog = GetErrorLogDataTable();

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(logPath);
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        DataRow row = errorLog.NewRow();
        row["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        row["filePath"] = filePath;
        errorLog.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    DataView dataView = new DataView(errorLog);
    dataView.Sort = sortExpression;
    errorLog = dataView.ToTable();
    DataTable pagedErrorLog = errorLog.Clone();

    for (int i = startRowIndex; i < startRowIndex + maximumRows; i++)
    {
        if (i >= errorLog.Rows.Count)
        {
            break;
        }
        pagedErrorLog.ImportRow(errorLog.Rows[i]);
    }

    if (pagedErrorLog.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        return errorLog;
    }
    else
    {
        return pagedErrorLog;
    }
}

private static DataTable GetErrorLogDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("fileName");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("filePath");
    return dataTable;
}
```